# how to change the background in the table depending on the value in the cell (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

the table component receives data from the parent and organizes them. After retrieving the table, the table is filled in again with data.

How to change the background of each cell depending on the value that is in it (using css styles?)

```
import React from 'react';
import '../layouts/table.css'

const Table = (props) => {

    let data = props.data

    let table = [
        ["city", "so2", "no2", "pm25", "pm10", "o3", "co"],
        ["2", "150", "1", "2", "5", "9", "10"],
        ["2", "250", "1", "2", "5", "9", "10"],
        ["2", "350", "1", "2", "5", "9", "10"],
        ["2", "450", "1", "2", "5", "9", "10"],
        ["2", "2", "1", "2", "5", "9", "10"],
        ["2", "10", "1", "2", "5", "9", "10"],
        ["2", "10", "1", "2", "5", "9", "10"],
        ["2", "10", "1", "2", "5", "9", "10"],
        ["2", "0", "1", "2", "5", "9", "10"],
    ]

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         //organizes the data and places it in the table
    }

    const row = table.map((table) =>
        <tr>
            <td scope="row" key={table[0][0]}>{table[0]}</td>
            <td id="so2" className="">{table[1]}</td>
            <td id="no2" className="">{table[2]}</td>
            <td id="pm24" className="">{table[3]}</td>
            <td id="pm10" className="">{table[4]}</td>
            <td id="o3" className="">{table[5]}</td>
            <td id="co" className="">{table[6]}</td>
        </tr>
    )

    return (

        <table id="table" className="table table-striped text-center">
            <thead className="table-primary">

                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">city</th>
                    <th scope="col">so2</th>
                    <th scope="col">no2</th>
                    <th scope="col">pm25</th>
                    <th scope="col">pm10</th>
                    <th scope="col">o3</th>
                    <th scope="col">co</th>
                </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>

                {row}

            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below:

```
const row = table.map((table) =>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row" key={table[0][0]}>{table[0]}</td>
        <td id="so2" style={{ color: table[1] != "soe2" ? 'blue': 'green'}}>{table[1]}</td>
        <td id="no2" style={{ color: table[2] != "soe2" ? 'blue': 'green'}}>{table[2]}</td>
        <td id="pm24" style={{ color: table[3] != "soe2" ? 'blue': 'green'}}>{table[3]}</td>
        <td id="pm10" style={{ color: table[4] != "soe2" ? 'blue': 'green'}}>{table[4]}</td>
        <td id="o3" style={{ color: table[5] != "soe2" ? 'blue': 'green'}}>{table[5]}</td>
        <td id="co" style={{ color: table[6] != "soe2" ? 'blue': 'green'}}>{table[6]}</td>
    </tr>
)
```

Comment: great solution if there are only two colors. How to do it for three colors?

Comment: You can use this and expand it do how many ever colours you want.

colorMe(value){
let class = "";
if(value ===) {
 class = "colour you desired."
}
return class
}
<td id="so2" className={this.colorMe(table[1])}>{table[1]}</td>

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as correct and an upvote wont hurt as well. :)